# Ionic 2 communicating with HTTPS server

Tags: ionic-framework, https, ionic2

I have an working ionic 2 app (running on **2.0.0-beta.4**), which communicate with my server using **HTTP POST**.

```
loginService(userID, pwd, userIpAddress){

    var body = 'userID=' +userID+"&pwd="+pwd+"&userIpAddress="+userIpAddress+'';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var url = 'http://localhost/WS/login.asmx';

    return this.http.post(url,body, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

How would I go around converting it into HTTPS POST, 
if the server would only accepts HTTPS POST requests?

How do I insert my self-signed certificates?

The closest I can find is [Node.JS HTTPS API](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)

Comment: Self signing certificate cannot be used in production. On Android debug mode, you can use it without inserting it

Comment: @e666, let's say i have the cert, the question is how do i go around implementing the https request?

Comment: Just use `https://localhost/WS/login.asmx` instead of `http://localhost/WS/login.asmx`

Comment: @e666, don't i need to import some certificates or smth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert your self-signed certificate, you need to mark your app as debuggable. However, this will enable the user to view the console logs.

To mark your app as debuggable, inside manifest file add this line `android:debuggable="true"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:debuggable="true">
      ...
    </application>
</manifest
```